# Matching the object key and add a new key and value into it using lodash

Tags: angularjs, lodash

I had an an object

```
 {
  sampletrue:{
  data1:'data',
  data2:'data'
   },
  samplefalse:{
  data1:'data',
  data2:'data'
 }   
}
```

Here, what i'm trying to do is with the object key name, i want to add a new key/value pair into it. Let's say for 'sampletrue' object i want to match the key name and if it has 'true' i need to add a new value as "resolve:'enable'"  and if it is 'false' i want to add "resolve:'disable'" I'm using lodash in my code.

Sample Output:

```
 {
sampletrue:{
data1:'data',
data2:'data',
 resolve:'enable'
 },
samplefalse:{
data1:'data',
data2:'data'
resolve:'disable' 
}   
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can find explanation in comments:

```js
var d = {
   sampletrue: {
     data1: 'data',
     data2: 'data'
   },
   samplefalse: {
     data1: 'data',
     data2: 'data'
   }
 }
// loop through the keys of the object with Object.keys() and forEach()
Object.keys(d).forEach(k => {
// we check with match method if the key (k) matches 'true'
  if (k.match(/true$/))
    d[k].resolve='enable' ;//if it matches assign resolve prop , 'enable' val
  
//same as above but with 'false'
  if (k.match(/false$/))
    d[k].resolve='disable' ;
})

console.log(d)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why do we need k>= just trying to understand

Comment: forEach()  is an array method that permits to loop, executing a function, through each array-entry; the first argument in the callback function is the item (in this case the key) . ForEach is a  fundamental in js so take your time and learn it  throughly

Comment: i tried using with lodash and it works awesome. Thanks for your answer though